# Angularjs filter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
  $scope.AddressData.Address = [
            {
                "LocationId": 66927,
                "ClientId": 114,
                "UserId": 431
            },
            {
                "LocationId": 66928,
                "ClientId": 114,
                "UserId": 431
            },
            {
                "LocationId": 66929,
                "ClientId": 114,
                "UserId": 431
            },
            {
                "LocationId": 66930,
                "ClientId": 114,
                "UserId": 431
            }
        ];
        var found = $filter('filter')($scope.AddressData.Address, { LocationId: '66927' }, true);
        console.log(found);
```

All looks okay to me, But this always returns a null array. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/146/ - is $scope.AddressData object ?

Comment: should be `Cannot set property 'Address' of undefined` exception, if your `AddressData` is not initialized

Comment: it's comparing by `angular.equals` which do a type and value checking on objects. you are comparing number to string here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [angular docs on filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), specifically the last argument to `$filter`:

> *comparator* true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

If you change your filter to:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.AddressData.Address, { LocationId: '66927' });
```

or:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.AddressData.Address, { LocationId: 66927 }, true);
```

It will work as expected.

Comment: That comment is using angular 1.0.5, a lot has changed between then and 1.3.8.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Angular will do an exact type check when using filter when you pass in true. Instead use locationId as an int:

```
var found = $filter('filter')($scope.AddressData.Address, { LocationId: 66927 }, true);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q57NSd3BFEcXizwuzRRJ?p=preview